# Can't get WebDAV to work

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, webdav

I've setup WebDAV feature for IIS and enabled it on my website, setup basic authentacation feature, added a WebDAV rule for the user, granted this user and IIS app pool user required filesystem access rights.
The client connection always return a "401 - unauthorized" error; IIS logs show this:

```
2017-02-01 06:58:19 W3SVC2 MyServer OPTIONS / - 443 - HTTP/1.1 NetBox/2.4.2+neon/0.30.2 - - myhost.com:443 200 0 0 405 138 234
2017-02-01 06:58:19 W3SVC2 MyServer PROPFIND / - 443 - HTTP/1.1 NetBox/2.4.2+neon/0.30.2 - - myhost.com:443 401 0 5 1541 258 218
```

So, it seems the problem is that the PROPFIND request fails due to auth error.
Any ideas what am I doing wrong? How can I fix or diagnose it?

Answer (score 0):

It's seem that your request do not have authentication you need to set Basic, Digest or Integrated Windows Authentication on the ISS side.

https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/iis/configuring_windows_authentication/

Are you sure that SSL is not an issue, if you are using virtual host it may cause issues with authentication.

Comment: I already set up the basic auth, read the question.

Comment: Yes but the logs do not display any auth information, I thin that the issue is located here, if you don't have any auth data on webdav you'll get 401 error

Comment: Any ideas how to diagnose it?

Comment: You can use Charles Web Proxy to trace the transactions with the server, after I can't guess where the configuration is buggy